# Loop to fill up .bash_history

Tags: bash, shell, loops, history

How would one write a loop to reach the limit on $HISTFILESIZE in bash?

Something like this that would actually print the commands?

```
for i in $(seq 1 $HISTFILESIZE); do echo test-$i;done
```

The goal is to see if logs can be overwritten with a simple loop that a malicious user might use to hide his shell history. I have .bash_history append only with: chattr +a
I know that relying on .bash_history is probably not the best way to keep track, this is more of a "I'm curious" question.

Thanks
Jon

Comment: I don't think there's a maximum size for that file. So it can become as big as the file system allows. Is there any reason why you want to do this? Perhaps we can solve your actual problem.

Comment: In addition to what siride said, what would this accomplish that deleting .bash_history would not

Comment: Sorry guys, I updated the question.

Comment: @siride: Bash limits the file to `$HISTFILESIZE` although it appears in my testing that this limit is ineffective if the file has been `chattr +a`.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson I just noticed that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `seq`, Bash has two ways of providing numbers to iterate over with a `for` loop.

```
for i in {1..100}
```

which won't take variables as arguments (unless you use `eval`).

And

```
for ((i = 1; i <= $HISTFILESIZE; i++))
```

which obviously can use variables.

You can do:

```
for ((i = 1; i <= $HISTFILESIZE; i++))
do
    history -s "anything you want"
done
```

With this technique a user can obliterate the in-memory history list of the current session. When the user exits, that list is written to the history file.

You can truncate the history file:

```
>~/.bash_history
```

Assuming it's not append-only.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the user could always run

```
for i in $(seq 1 $HISTFILESIZE); do echo test-$i;done
```

just as you say, and paste the output into a terminal. But `.bash_history` is in the user's home directory, so he could `chmod +w` and then `shred` it just as easily.

Comment: When setting .bash_history as append only via chattr +a while root, the normal user is unable to change file modes.